# I don't know how to use class types as parameter

Tags: java, interface, type-parameter, getconstructor

So I am creating a spigot plugin but that's not so important.

I have a **Selection** class that keeps information about a 2D area with the x,z,width,depth stuff. At a certain point a rectangle or an ellipse will be stuffed into that selection. My Ellipse and Rectangle class implement an interface **Shape**.

In the consturctor of Selection I'd like to determine the type of later used shape. My first idea was to pass the class type

```
public Selection(Class<Shape> shapeType) {
```

so I could just create an object of that class afterwards

```
Constructor<Shape> cons = shapeType.getConstructor(//Well I also don't know what belongs here);
Shape s = cons.newInstance(this);
```

Well in the end I got a NullpointerException because the Shape interface does not have a constructor.

I am just confused. Shall I change the Shape interface to an abstract class or just pass some ints like *ELLIPSE* and *RECTANGLE* in the constructor? Does anybody have an idea what I could do?

Thanks in advance Mighty One

Comment: Don't do this: pass in a `Supplier<? extends Shape>`, e.g. `Rectangle::new` or `() -> new Ellipse(10, 20)`.

Comment: Agree with that ^^ but if you must use newInstance() the correct thing to pass in is a Class<? extends Shape>. Then it will accept Rectangle.class etc

Comment: Avoid answering questions in comments ^^

Answer (score 5):

Don't do this.

What you are trying to do is to pass in "a thing which gives me a thing". What you're actually passing in is "a thing which gives access to things which give you things".

A Class gives you access to zero or more constructors; it doesn't guarantee that there is one you can invoke with particular parameters to give you an instance. The problem that you've found using reflection is that you have no guarantee of the existence of the constructor.

Take a simpler approach: pass in a `Supplier<? extends Shape>`, e.g. `Rectangle::new` or `() -> new Ellipse(10, 20)`. This is checked at compile time to ensure that the constructor exists.

Comment: In my case the supplier won't work I think. All Shapes also expect an Selection in their constructer which wouldn't exist at this point yet. I came along with *public Selection (Class <? extends Shape> type) {* and *Constructer <? extends Shape> cons = type.getConstructor (Selection.class);*

Comment: In that case you need a `Function<Selection, Shape>` (or, more generally, a `Function<? super Selection, ? extends Shape>`.

Comment: Or if you need 2 parameters, a `BiFunction`; or if you need more, define your own interface.